# Folders and invalid files can't be dragged to upload

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, folder

I am using SharePoint server 2013 and I need to drag and drop folders in a SharePoint library. I am searching for the easiest way for a simple user to upload files and folders! I made some researches and one of the solutions is to open the document library with explorer view and then drag and drop the folders.

Is there any way, please, to drag and drop the folders directly in the browser (with a simple click as the files)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After spending few days searching, I noticed that drag and drop the folders to the document library is not possible! The only  solution is even to create the folder and then drag and drop the files or copy paste the folders through windows explorer.